# Please help with discrete notation for predicate comparisons.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I'm working on writing a proof and I'm a bit stuck on one part in particular.

Here's an example of the type of problem I'm working with.

$Let\ C(x)\ and\ P(x)\ be\ defined\ as:$

$C(x) = "This\ post\ was\ uploaded\ on\ x."$
$P(x) ="x\ comes\ after\ Monday\ and\ before\ Wednesday"$.

$\ \ \ \ \ \ $ If I were to write: $C("Tuesday") \neq P("Tuesday")$ the answer would be $False$ (today is Tuesday), however I want to compare the contents of the two statements, not the logical outcome. I want to show that the two statements $P(x)$ and $C(x)$ are different because they are talking about different things -- getting a $True$ value (in this case) as output. Specific context within the statements isn't really important to the larger proof I'm working on; the specific contents don't matter, just the fact that they're different. The order in which things were stated doesn't matter either.

How would one go about writing this using discrete notation?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C and P are equivalent single place predicates when
for all x, (C(x) iff P(x)).

Thus to say they are logical different is equivalent to
not for all x, (C(x) iff P(x)).

Comment: The terseness of this response (and omission of proper math formatting) may limit its usefulness to future Readers.  Since the OP asks about "using discrete notation", they may find some discussion of the choice of notation helpful as well.

Comment: I second hardmath's comment. I'm not too sure what you're writing. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @hardmath.  See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  Using MathJax would allow $\lnot \forall x\; (C(x) \iff P(x))$.

Comment: @user3164238.  See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm familiar with the notation used here but I'm only partially certain of what this comparison is 'doing'. Is this conceptually similar to how a bijection between two sets works (ie. each element in set A maps to exactly one element in set B and each element in set B maps to exactly one element in set A)?

Comment: Nothing like a bijection but equality between sets.